# XAML DispatcherTimer Interval Too Slow

Tags: c#, windows-8, timer, windows-store-apps

I need to count very fast for my Windows 8 Store Application. So i set the interval to 10 Ticks. As we have 10,000,000 ticks per second that should be enough. But i only get around 30 ticks as a result. How do i get a faster timer?

My code for the timer (and control timer):

```
    int GLOBAL_counter = 0;

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromTicks(10);
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
        timer.Start();

        DispatcherTimer timerControl = new DispatcherTimer();
        timerControl.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        timerControl.Tick += timer_Tick_timerControl;
        timerControl.Start();
    }

    private void timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        GLOBAL_counter++;
    }

    private void timer_Tick_timerControl(object sender, object e)
    {
        Label1.Text += GLOBAL_counter.ToString() + "\r\n";
        GLOBAL_counter = 0;
    }
```

Comment: Is 10 million / 30 = ~333 thousand timer fires / sec not enough? That's a *lot*. To be fair, if you plan to do any actual work on each tick, you'll of course end up with lower throughput (since the dispatcher thread will be briefly busy with your work.) Could you elaborate on the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: it does fire, but only 30 times a second. it should be much more. i need like 1000 a second.

Answer (score 1):

From MSDN description of DispatcherTimer class:

> Timers are not guaranteed to execute exactly when the time interval
>   occurs, but they are guaranteed to not execute before the time
>   interval occurs. This is because DispatcherTimer operations are placed
>   on the Dispatcher queue like other operations. When the
>   DispatcherTimer operation executes is dependent on the other jobs in
>   the queue and their priorities.

Comment: So how can we get `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` like functionality in Windows Store apps? I believe we cannot use Windows Forms controls in the store apps?